# Opening file with associated program

Tags: delphi, winapi

I have SpeedButton on my form and I want it open avi file with associated program.I tried Windows.winexec but it doesn't seem to be worked.

Comment: Where do people *still* read about using WinExec? It's been deprecated for almost 15 years!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You want ShellExecute - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153%28VS.85%29.aspx for the API and also this link http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/a/executeprogram.htm for details of how to use it from Delphi.

Comment: I tried but it gives compilation error: Undeclared identifier

Comment: If it doesn't compile, edit your question to include the code that doesn't compile.

Comment: @Azad Salahli, add `ShellApi` in the `uses`.